# Item Height in Tree View does not change despite of sending message with Perform

Tags: delphi, treeview, height

I have a Tree View as a main menu. After program start, I add new sub items.

Then I do `TreeView1.Perform(TVM_SETITEMHEIGHT, 28, 0);`

At designtime I set the Form's `Position` property to `poDesigned`. Why does `TreeView1.Perform` not work if I do `Position := poScreenCenter;` in runtime?

This is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu1');
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu2');
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu3');
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu4');
  TreeView1.Perform(TVM_SETITEMHEIGHT, 28, 0);
  Position:=poScreenCenter;
end;
```

Comment: TVM_SETITEMHEIGHT just works here, whether an root item is selected or a subitem, and whether an item is collapsed or expanded, and whether the TreeView is focussed or enabled or not. What do you mean with "_When a program closed_"?

Comment: Or do you want to change only the height of the selected item? See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773761(v=vs.85).aspx): _To modify the height of individual items, see the description of the iIntegral member of the TVITEMEX structure._

Comment: I want to change the height of all elements. It does not matter what a state

Comment: "When a program closed" ->save to a registry a selected item

Comment: No way saving something to the registry is the cause. Do you do custom painting? Could that be the cause?

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with the code you use to write to/read from the registry?  Might be worth including that in your question, if it's part of the process generating the problematic behavior.

Comment: I have found the issue: if I have form1.Position:=poScreenCenter in a Design Time and do form1.Position:=poDesigned and set L-T-H-W window position in a Run Time then TreeView1.Perform(TVM_SETITEMHEIGHT, 28, 0); does not work!!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that setting the Position property of the Form results in call to RecreateWnd. RecreateWnd means destroying the windows screen object and building it up from scratch. It seems this is needed (or te most easiest way) to fully implement all the effects of changing this property. Recreation of window handles is not uncommon: e.g. changing the BorderStyle of a form, or even that of an Edit control results in a call to RecreateWnd.

RecreateWnd cascades into recreating all child windowed controls, also your TreeView. Normally, a component knows from its internals (properties, private data) how to recreate itself. For instance: a TreeView saves its nodes to a temporary memory stream prior to handle destruction, and loads it back in after handle recreation.

So, who is to blame: the Position property of the Form, the TreeView, or neither? In the absence of a ItemHeight property for the TreeView, you are forced to manually send a WinAPI message. And that is a modification to the control which is not registered by the VCL. So far the explanation as why this happens.

The best solution is to be sure your customization is done every time the TreeView is recreated. Unfortunately there is no event available for that. You would need to override CreateWnd (see update below). But when you leave the Ctl3D and BorderStyle properties intact, it is also possible to control this at the parent's level. I came down to overriding CM_ShowingChanged, because the TreeView unfortunately isn't yet completely rebuild after TForm1.CreateWnd:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  TreeView1: TTreeView;
  ...
private
  procedure CMShowingChanged(var Message: TMessage);
    message CM_SHOWINGCHANGED;
end;

procedure TForm1.CMShowingChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  TreeView1.Perform(TVM_SETITEMHEIGHT, 28, 0);
end;
```

### Update:

As requested in below comment, here is the solution with overriden TTreeView.CreateWnd:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes, Controls, Forms, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, CommCtrl, XPMan;

type
  TTreeView = class(ComCtrls.TTreeView)
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    XPManifest1: TXPManifest;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TTreeView }

procedure TTreeView.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited CreateWnd;
  Perform(TVM_SETITEMHEIGHT, 38, 0);
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu1');
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu2');
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu3');
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu4');
  Position := poScreenCenter;
end;

end.
```

And if you don't like to subclass TTreeView, then override CreateWnd of the form, but in that case you need to call HandleNeeded as answered by [Andreas Rejbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632337/item-height-in-tree-view-does-not-change-despite-of-sending-message-with-perform/6638300#6638300):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes, Controls, Forms, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, CommCtrl, XPMan;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    XPManifest1: TXPManifest;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu1');
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu2');
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu3');
  TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items.Item[0],'Sub Menu4');
  Position := poScreenCenter;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited CreateWnd;
  TreeView1.HandleNeeded;
  TreeView1.Perform(TVM_SETITEMHEIGHT, 38, 0);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Guys, both answers are good, please, tell what is the best, how do you fill? NGLN has an excellent explanation.

Comment: @maxfax Well, strictly speaking, both are in their current form not optimal. CM_SHOWINGCHANGED is called not only when recreating the window. But @Andreas's solution doesn't take care of other recreation triggers (there aren't thát many in the default VCL, but you never know e.g. what 3rd party libraries might do to a form). The best is to combine both: override CreateWnd (instead of CMShowingChanged) and add Andreas' HandleNeeded.

Comment: Can you show how to "override CreateWnd" please? The question is open.

Comment: For the second example - I have en error: Exception class EReadError with message 'Error reading StatusBar1.Left: Access violation at address...I create a progress bar in a status bar.

Comment: For the first one: Exception class EInvalidCast with message 'Invalid class typecast' -on TForm2.TreeView2Changing, here: 'if Assigned((Sender as TTreeView).Selected) and  Assigned(TTreeView(Sender).Selected.Data) then'

Comment: 1st: That is because now there are two TTreeView declarations, one in this unit and one in ComCtrls. The former is not compatible with the latter. If you have to use TTreeView for typecasting, then specify its type as `ComCtrls.TTreeView`.

Comment: ok, the first solution works without errors, but it does not do what I need:( the hight does not change

Comment: Well sorry, but then I cannot help you further. Both work just fine here. Maybe it's an >D7 issue, but I don't think so. Does this also not work in a new test-project? Maybe you could upload your app somewhere so we could try to track the problem?

Answer (score 8):

NGLN's answer gives the explanation for the problem.

If you need only to set the `Position` (or any other property of the form that will cause the window (in the technical sense) to be recreated) at the same time you set the height of the tree-view items, you can do

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Position := poDesigned;
  TreeView1.HandleNeeded;
  TreeView1.Perform(TVM_SETITEMHEIGHT, 28, 0);
end;
```