# Newline character in caption of button

Tags: delphi

I am building an application in which I want to display a button on a form. I want to display the Caption of the button on two lines. I have tried using the following code in the form's OnCreate event but it is not showing the new line.

```
Button.Caption := 'Hello' + #13#10 + 'world';
```

Any other method to add a new line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**For *very old* Delphi versions which do not have the WordWrap property:**

Use following code prior to setting the caption:

```
SetWindowLong(Button1.Handle, GWL_STYLE, 
  GetWindowLong(Button1.Handle, GWL_STYLE) or BS_MULTILINE);
```

But the tricky part is that this code needs execution on a number of occasions. When the button is recreated, then your multiline setting is lost. Kind of similar to [this dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632337/item-height-in-tree-view-does-not-change-despite-of-sending-message-with-perform/6638294#6638294).

Luckily the VCL provides a solution, but you have to subclass the TButton type, e.g. as follows:

```
type
  TButton = class(StdCtrls.TButton)
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)

...

procedure TButton.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.Style := Params.Style or BS_MULTILINE;
end;
```

Comment: `TButton.CreateParams` would be a more natural place than ` TButton.CreateWnd`, for your first suggestion. I'm not sure that your second suggestion would work.

Comment: @David Agreed, that is much better!

Answer (score 9):

Set WordWrap to True. That's all.

Comment: I m unable to find that property in button class. can u plz tel which claas contains this property. thanks for reply.

Comment: TButton and TBitBtn have WordWrap property.

Comment: @naren: You haven't specified your Delphi version. Maybe older Delphis didn't have that property.

Answer (score 5):

Others have told you what you can do in code: set `Wordwrap` and use `SLineBreak`.

But I guess you'd like to edit the multiple lines in the designer. This is not possible in the plain IDE. There are a few 3rd party tools which allow it, but you can also simply use a `'|'` to separate the lines, and then, in code use something like

```
Button1.Caption := 
  StringReplace(Button1.Caption, '|', SLineBreak, [rfReplaceAll]);
```

(This is from memory, as I have no Delphi here, so please use the proper syntax).

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted. This is how I have done it in my own code and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

In the System.pas (which automatically gets used) the following is defined:

```
const sLineBreak = {$IFDEF LINUX} AnsiChar(#10) {$ENDIF} 
                   {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} AnsiString(#13#10) {$ENDIF};
```

So if you want to make your Button wrap, make sure AutoSize is set to true, and then use the following code:

button.Caption := 'Line one'+sLineBreak+'Line two';

Comment: TButton doesn't have an AutoSize property.

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi 2007 you can use this:

```
SpeedButton1.Caption := 'first line' + #13 + 'second line';
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to see to see the change in IDE, at design time, you can do the following:

1. Right click in the control and select *"View as Text"*.
2. Locate the control and at the spot you want the line break, add to the value of *Caption*, the characters `'#13#10'` (CRLF).
3. Right click and select *"View as Form"*.
4. Check the property `WordWrap` of the button control.

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of Delphi the Tspeedbutton only responsive for manually created strings with CRLF. Not regular TButton. This is if you do not want to hack TButton class as suggested in the best answer above.