# Inno Setup button caption with line breaks

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to create a button caption that contains a line break:

```
Button.Caption := 'Line1' + #13#10 + 'Line2';
```

However, the standard line break character `#13#10` does not appear to work in this case as I am getting:

> Line1Line2

displayed on the button. What is the correct syntax to break a button caption across more than one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Newline character in caption of button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6912900/850848) (in Delphi):

```pascal
function GetWindowLong(Wnd: HWnd; Index: Integer): LongInt;
  external 'GetWindowLongW@user32.dll stdcall';
function SetWindowLong(Wnd: HWnd; Index: Integer; NewLong: LongInt): LongInt;
  external 'SetWindowLongW@user32.dll stdcall';

const
  GWL_STYLE = -16;
  BS_MULTILINE = $2000;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  Button: TNewButton;
begin
  Button := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  Button.Left := ScaleX(16);
  Button.Top := WizardForm.NextButton.Top - ScaleX(8);
  Button.Width := WizardForm.NextButton.Width;
  Button.Height := WizardForm.NextButton.Height + ScaleY(16);
  Button.Parent := WizardForm;

  SetWindowLong(Button.Handle, GWL_STYLE, 
    GetWindowLong(Button.Handle, GWL_STYLE) or BS_MULTILINE);

  Button.Caption := 'foo' + #13#10 + 'bar';
end;
```

[image: Button with new line]